# Calling other callback from callback class

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using the callback class like
class X{ callback(){} X(){ros::publisher sub1 = n.subscribe(&callback); callback();} run()};

but can you do from this callback method: callback(){ ros::publisher sub2 = n.subscribe(&callback2); callback2():}. I couldn't find about this.

I hope the question is clear. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73264/calling-other-callback-from-callback-class/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code is a bit fuzzy and won't compile, but in principle yes, you can do all of that.

A callback is just a method that you can call manually if you need to. You can also create subscriptions whenever you want.

There is only one flaw in your code: The subscribers/publishers are declared locally, so once the function is done, they will be destroyed.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2013-08-16**:
You say the code won't compile. Assuming you don't mean my example code (which indeed won't compile), can you please explain why ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-16**:
For example, you're assigning a publisher to the result of a subscribe call...